# MariaDB comparison between char and number

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am so confused by the following query

```
SELECT 
 '6217001180007179362' = 6217001180007179156      -- 1
 , 6217001180007179362 = 6217001180007179156   ;  -- 0
```

how come 「'6217001180007179362' = 6217001180007179156」 is 1 ?

my maria DB verision is 10.2.11-MariaDB.

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a series of digits in MariaDB/MySQL, it is interpreted as a numeric constant.  In your case, this does what you want.

When you enter a series of digits surrounded by single quotes, then it is interpreted as a string.

When you compare two numeric constants -- well, there isn't a problem.  The solution is what you expect.

However, if one is a string, then the values are implicitly converted.  They fall under this condition, as described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Your values have more precision than can be represented in a float, so they values look equal to MySQL.

Comment: `DOUBLE` has about 16 significant digits.  And that is about where they differ.